# Why does my app read data of the previously logged in user instead of the current one until I kill & relaunch a couple of times?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I press the "Greet" button in my app, it is supposed to display a message saying "Welcome, (FirstName)". For example, if my first user "John" logs in, presses the button, and receives a "Welcome John" alert, but if he logs out, and "Smith" logs in, pressing the button still continues to display "Welcome John" until I kill my app and relaunch (within the simulator). I have stored user data on Cloud Firestore, and obviously read data from there.

I'm don't think this is a simulator issue, because downloading the app on my device has the same result. Since I do not have access to 2 devices presently, I have yet to ascertain what happens if two users log in on different devices and press the Greet button.

My query snapshot code is as follows:

```
guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
emailString = "\(email)"

self.db.collection("users").whereField("email", isEqualTo: emailString)
.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            greetingLabel.text =  document.get("Name") as! String
        }
    }
}
```

here is my logout function:

```
    func signOut() {
    print("signout")
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginVc())
        navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch let error {
        print("Failed to sign out, \(error)")
    }
}
```

here is the greeting set up:

```
lazy var nameString = ""


@objc func greetButtonPressed() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello, ", message: "\(nameString)", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true)



    func loadUserData() {
        guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
        emailString = "\(email)"

        self.db.collection("users").whereField("email", isEqualTo: emailString).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error retrieving the document: \(error)")
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    self.nameString = document.get("name") as! String
                    print(self.nameString)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you logout do you use the Auth logout method?

Comment: thank you for replying, yes I do, I have edited the question to show my logout method

Comment: Can you please add the alert and greet button?

Comment: added the greeting set up!